# Django returns model objects in random order after app rename

Tags: django, postgresql

I've renamed an app in my Django project, trying to follow all 'best practices', that is, I renamed project folders, migrations (in project + PostgreSQL), DB content types and table names.

Everything works fine, except one thing: the order of the objects returned by `myfavmodel.objects.all()` appears to be random, that is, NOT sorted by increasing ID, yet it is always the same when I call `myfavmodel.objects.all()`. Even more strange is that some models in the renamed app show this behaviour while others show the normal one, that is, their objects are returned sorted by increasing ID.

I can solve the problem rather easily by adding `ordering = ['id']` to the Meta class of my models but I would like to understand what is causing this behaviour.

`myfavmodel.objects.all()[:20].values_list('id', flat=True)`

returns

`[709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 1095, 394]`

but the equivalent SQL query does not

```
select id from myfavmodel limit 20;

 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15
 16
 17
 18
 19
 20
(20 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Django**, the default ordering of model objects is determined by the `ordering` attribute in the model's `Meta` class. If this attribute is not defined, then the default ordering is `undefined`, and the database backend may return the objects in any order.

The order of the objects returned by `myfavmodel.objects.all()` is not guaranteed to be sorted by increasing ID unless you explicitly specify the default `ordering`.

It's generally recommended to define a default `ordering` that can be used efficiently by the database backend, and to use `order_by()` to specify alternative orderings when necessary.

Comment: I did read that in another post, but it is also true that before the rename, the records were always returned in order of ascending ID for all models, without setting any ordering in the Meta class, so that was just a coincidence then?